# Delete every other item in the array until only one is left

Tags: arrays, ruby

My problem is asking to iterate over an array of items and delete every other item until I reach the end of the array when I should start iterating backwards and keep deleting every other item and so on back and forth until only one item is left in the array.

for example: 1,2,3,4,5, would become 1,3,5 and then 3

I understand that I shouldn't be deleting from the original array so I created another array that just keeps every other item while decreasing its size but I can't get it to work and end up with an infinite loop.

```
arr=*(1..10)
s_arr=[]
until s_arr.length==1 
i=0
   while i<arr.length
   s_arr.push(arr[i])
   i+=2
end
   arr=s_arr.reverse
   s_arr=arr
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: What would be the output for `arr = *(1..10)`? doesn't `(0...arr.size).each { |index| [index, -index].each { |el| arr.delete_at el  } }` work?

Comment: What would the output be for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: Hello Sebastian this line  arr = *(1..10) can be just substituted by any array lets say arr = [2,21,1,5,6,12,100,9,17]
After running your code on this array I am left with two elements 
=>[6, 9]
And I need to end with just one. Any thoughts? 
Also how does -index  in your code work? I've never used with a minus before. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you be left with two elements? Your specification says "and so on back and forth *until only **one** item is left in the array*"

Comment: Hello  Jörg W Mittag - I'm not sure I'm following you. I was just saying that after running the code suggested by Sebastian (not by me)  was leaving me with 2 elements instead of just one (like I needed it to be)

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration, replace the array with a version with every other element dropped

```
arr = *(1..10)

while arr.length > 1
  arr = arr.select.with_index { |_, i| i % 2 == 0 }.reverse
end
```

This doesn't match your example, but your example seems inconsistent in the first place. If [1,2,3,4,5] goes to [1,3,5], then the next step should be [1,5] instead of [3].

Comment: You are absolutely right. I miscalculated. Can you explain the underscore please. I know it stands for a variable that we don't care about but how does it apply here when we are already eliminating the even numbers with i%2==0?

Comment: `.select.with_index` passes two arguments to the block: the element of the array and its index. We only use the index to determine which elements to keep, so the first argument is safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @Max's answer, but implemented recursively.

```
def last_one_standing(arr)
  return arr.first if arr.size == 1
  last_one_standing arr.select.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }.reverse
end

(1..16).each { |i| puts "1..%d: %d" % [i, last_one_standing((1..i).to_a)] }
1..1:   1
1..2:   1
1..3:   3
1..4:   3
1..5:   1
1..6:   1
1..7:   3
1..8:   3
1..9:   9
1..10:  9
1..11: 11
1..12: 11
1..13:  9
1..14:  9
1..15: 11
1..16: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=*(1..10)

s_arr=[]

until s_arr.length == 1
  i=0
  while i < arr.length
    s_arr.push(arr[i])
    i+=2
  end

  arr=s_arr.reverse

  if s_arr.length != 1
    s_arr=[]
  end

end
```

Your problem was setting the s_arr array the same as the arr. Then you must add a conditional to tell it to stop when it does reach 1 otherwise it'll become 0 instead.

EDIT:

```
arr=*(1..10)

s_arr=[]

until s_arr.length == 1
  s_arr = []
  i=0
  while i < arr.length
    s_arr.push(arr[i])
    i+=2
  end
  arr=s_arr.reverse
end
```

even better solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Great solution. So by adding the condition /   if s_arr.length != 1  /  we make sure that as soon as it reaches the length of 1 it breaks the loop?

Comment: Yes. You could also probably move the s_arr where the i=0 is.

Comment: I don't understand half the people on this site, the guy asked for help with his code not help him create something else completely.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this so you can take advantage of Ruby's power

```
result = []
array.each_with_index {|val,idx| result << val if ( idx % 2 == 0)}
```

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question as you have simply returned an array of elements whose indices are even numbers. Though not directly relevant, your code can be simplified to `array.select.with_index { |val,idx| idx.even? }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Appreciated your correction, and I like your proposal

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your ruby console:

```
arr=*(1..10)

x = (Math::log(arr.length) / Math::log(3)).to_i

3**x
```

Comment: This warrants some mathematical justification, if it works at all.

Comment: I admire your attempt to derive a closed-form solution, but this is not correct. If, for example,  `arr = [1,2,3,4,5]; x = (Math::log(arr.length) / Math::log(3)).to_i # 1; 3**x #=> 3`. After, we have `[1,3,5]` after the first (left-right) pass, then `[1,5]` after the second (right-to-left) pass, and lastly `[1]`.